# sqlalchemy returns list of tuples and not just a value for a simple "select...where" query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I know some SQL from using PHP but SQLAlchemy I am stumbling on.
My first query:

```
engine.table_names()

from sqlalchemy import select, Table, Column, String,\
    MetaData
sql = "select id from user where email = 'omg@gmail.com'"
conn=engine.connect()
res_proxy = conn.execute(sql)
res = res_proxy.fetchall()
user_id = res[0][0]
print(res[0][0])
row = res[0]
print(row.keys())
print(res)
```

This outputs

```
1
['id']
[(1,)]
```

My second query

```
#query meals table and get highest meal number
sql2 = "select meal_id from user_meals where user_id='user_id'"
res_proxy = conn.execute(sql2)
res = res_proxy.fetchall()
print(res)
```

Outputs

```
[]
```

It's an empty table so that is correct.
Why are the return values lists and in the first query a list of tuple?

Comment: You can think of the `list` as the resultset, and the `tuple`s as the rows in the resultset.

Comment: If you know that the query will return only one row you can get the tuple directly by calling `res_proxy.fetchone()`.  But SQLAlchemy isn't going to switch the types of the response based on the number of records returned, the programmer needs to select the method they want to use.